# How to apply more than one JavaScript onchange for multiple image upload input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I have a page where users can upload up to 5 images to their post. For clarity for the user I have made it so that there are 5 empty boxes with separate input fields like this:

```html
<span id="enableFileUpload_1" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
  <input id="imageUploadID_1" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
</span>
<span id="enableFileUpload_2" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
  <input id="imageUploadID_2" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
</span>
```

To handle these I have some JavaScript which looks for onchange event on the first field:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var imageNumber = 1;
    $('body').on('change', '#imageUploadID_'+imageNumber, function() {
        $this = $(this);
        file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
        form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');
        form_data.append('security', blog.security);

        $.ajax({
            url: blog.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine for the first image but it seems like `imageNumber` is always 1 so the onchange event only fires for the first image/input and does nothing for the rest.

**Questions**

1. Do I have to write 5 different `$('body').on('change', '#imageUploadID_1', function()` for each input field and then have them call the same function?
2. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to assign the same onClick handler to every span with a class of `upload-image-svg-wrapper`. You've already written the code within the handler to work on any image that is clicked because you've used `this` to get the form data.

```
$('span.upload-image-svg-wrapper > input').on('change', function() {
```

Above, instead of selecting the entire body of the document we instruct jQuery to select all `span`s with the class `upload-image-svg-wrapper` that are inputs. And then we remove the selector from the on change handler.

Comment: Thank you, this is much smarter! I am pretty new to jQuery, thanks for the nice solution. For anyone wondering I had to add a "> input" to make it "span.upload-image-svg-wrapper > input"

Comment: Sorry I missed the input in the original answer. It's updated now in case someone else stumbles across this answer.